# Segmention Fault after entering the first element

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after I enter the first element of the matrix. I know Segmentation fault occurs when the something is tried to accessed which is not physically in the memory, but I am not getting why this error is occuring here.

I am using pointers on purpose because I am learning the usage of pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i, j, m, n;
    int **p, **q, **res;
    p = (int**) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    q = (int**) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    res = (int**) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
        {
            scanf("%d", &(*(*(p+i)+j)));
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<m;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d      ", (*(*(p+i)+j)));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf() does not ignore the carriage return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various errors in your code.
I have inlined the comments to the changes. I have removed `q` and `res`.

There are two variants of the code, one using a single "block" of memory of size `m * n` and another using one block of memory of size `m` to keep `m` pointers to `m` other blocks of memory of size `n`.

**using a single "block" of memory of size `m * n`**
*useful when n is constant for each of the m lines*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int i,j,m,n;

    /* Changed to *p. Instead of an array of arrays 
       you'll use a single block of memory */
    int *p;

    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

    /* m rows and n columns = m * n "cells" */
    p = (int*) malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            /* the element at row i and column j is the (i * m) + j 
               element of the block of memory, so p + (i*m) + j .
               It's already an address to memory, so you don't need the & */
            scanf("%d", (p + (i*m) + j));
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            /* same as before, but this time you have 
               to dereference the address */
            printf("%d      ", *(p + (i*m) + j));
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

**using one block of memory of size `m` to keep `m` pointers to `m` other blocks of memory of size `n`**
*useful when n is variable for each of the m lines ("jagged" arrays)*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int i,j,m,n;
    int **p;

    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);

    /* We will have m "rows", each element a ptr to a full row of n columns 
       Note that each element has size == sizeof(int*) because it's a ptr
       to an array of int */
    p = (int**) malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        /* For each row we have to malloc the space for the 
           columns (elements) */
        *(p + i) = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            /* Compare the reference to the one before, note
               that we first dereference *(p + i) to get the
               ptr of the i row and then to this ptr we add
               the column index */
            scanf("%d", *(p + i) + j);
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            /* Note the double dereferencing, first to the address 
               of the row of data
               and then to the exact column */
            printf("%d      ", *(*(p + i) + j));
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you don't actually allocate memory for the data inside `p` or `q` or `res`. You allocate size for ten integers, but you should start by allocateing for ten integer *pointers* and then allocate for the data inside that.

So like this:

```
/* Get `m` and `n`... */

p = malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    p[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

This of course have to be done for the others too.

---

Also, you *do* know that you can access these using the same syntax as arrays? No need for the pointer arithmetic or pointer dereference. Just a simple `p[i][j]` will work fine.

Comment: Yea, knew about the p[i][j] format but i specifically wanted to use the pointer '*' and '&' operators wherever possible so that I can learn better. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It starts here:

```
 p = (int**) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

As `p` ist `int **` this should be

```
 p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
```

Now you have allocated memory for 10 pointers, but still no memory for the individual ints. So add

```
for( i=0; i<10; i++ )
     p[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

Noy you can use `&(*(*(p+i)+j)` (i would prefer to write `&p[i][j]` ) for 0 <= i,j < 10;
The same would apply to `q` and `res` too, if you had used them